# Compile libgdiplus source to create statically linked library i.e. libgdiplus.so

Tags: c++, gcc, mono, configure

I have downloaded the libgdiplus source from https://github.com/mono/libgdiplus/archive/master.tar.gz

How should I compile it to create statically linked library? The reason behind it is I dont want user to install all the dependencies that libgdiplus.so require to run a program.

I tried 
`./configure --enable-static` and `./configure LDFLAGS=-static` and checked the output in /src/.libs directory but I did not find statically linked shared object library there. I want to distribute it with my program which uses embedded Mono.net.

Thanks,
Omkay

Comment: What is the platform you are targeting? OS X , Linux,.. ?

Comment: Have you added VERBOSE=1 to the make command line, to confirm flags are really reaching gcc?

Comment: ".so" is dynamically loaded library. ".a" is statically linked library. So, what do you really want to build?

Answer (score 0):

General :

```
./configure --enable-static --prefix=/usr
mkdir SOMEDIR
INSTALL_ROOT=SOMEDIR make INSTALL
```

should make things simpler for searching.

Please also beware that in order to get a no-dependencies archive, you’ll need to have all the dependencies of libgdiplus availaible as static archives. If some of them are installed only as shared objects, you programs linked against on your libgdiplus.a will require those .so dependencies at run-time.